# how to handle slot filling using actions-on-google node.js library

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have one intent where I have enabled slot filling but don't know how to get the parameters from slot filling using actions-on-google node.js library

[image]

I want the values of these parameters in response and also want to prompt the user if he has not provided any parameter.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, and you should probably update it to be more clear. Are you saying you have turned on "Enable webhook call for slot filling"? Can you illustrate how you have your slots and Intents set and what is/isn't working? StackOverflow works best when you have tried to solve the problem yourself but have run into problems, can illustrate the steps you've taken, and provide info so we can duplicate or review to help point you in the right direction - see [How Do I Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? The more you provide - the better we can help.

Comment: @Prisoner I have updated my question please have a look.

Comment: Why do you want to enable slot filling in your webhook? It looks like you already have the prompts defined in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you have "Enable webhook call for slot filling" set to true for an Intent, then the webhook will be called every time a slot needs filling (unless another Intent matches the user response better) until all the slots are filled. The parameters will include those slots set so far, the Intent display name will be set so you know which Intent is being worked on, and the field `allRequiredParamsSet` will be false until (you guessed it) all the required slots have been filled.

As [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook-slot-filling) says:

> Dialogflow sends a fulfillment webhook request for each conversational turn during slot filling.

and

> The webhook request message received by your webhook service has a queryResult.parameters field. This field contains the current set of parameters provided by the end-user. Values that have not been collected yet are set to empty strings.